# Theano function memory not allocated in Keras example

Tags: python, keras, theano, handwriting-recognition

I am using Keras OCR example: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py for online handwriting recognition but facing a memory allocation problem after model training while using a theano function to get the softmax output. 
Shape of x_train: (1200,1586,4). I am feeding 1200 stroke sequences in batches of 12.
Here's the code snippet:

```
inputs = Input(name='the_input', shape=x_train.shape[1:], dtype='float32')
rnn_encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer=init,bias_initializer=bias),name='bidirectional_1',merge_mode='concat',trainable=trainable)(inputs)
birnn_encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer=init,bias_initializer=bias),name='bidirectional_2',merge_mode='concat',trainable=trainable)(rnn_encoded)
trirnn_encoded=Bidirectional(LSTM(16,return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer=init,bias_initializer=bias),name='bidirectional_3',merge_mode='concat',trainable=trainable)(birnn_encoded)
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(28, name='dense',kernel_initializer=init,bias_initializer=bias))(trirnn_encoded)
y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(output)
model=Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=y_pred)
labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[max_len], dtype='int32') 
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length])
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)
opt=RMSprop(lr=0.001,clipnorm=1.)
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer=opt)
gc.collect()
my_generator = generator(x_train,y_train,batch_size)
hist= model.fit_generator(my_generator,epochs=80,steps_per_epoch=100,shuffle=True,use_multiprocessing=False,workers=1)
model.save(mfile)
test_func = K.function([inputs], [y_pred])
```

The memory allocation error occurs at the last line. I am using a 32GB RAM machine with 8vCPUs on AWS. The error doesn't occur when I run the code for less number of epochs (around 30-40) but mostly when I run for large number of epochs like 80-100. I have attached a screenshot of the error also.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qCmc.png) Please suggest me if there is any solution to the problem other than reducing dataset size or number of epochs.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to remove the memory error but I was able to get the test results. I just saved this model and loaded it later in another script. While loading, I used the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283356/saving-and-restoring-keras-blstm-ctc-model) to get the same test function from the model and gave it train/test data in a loop to obtain the decoded strings and calculate accuracy. This doesn't cause any memory errors also.